# Java: REST service URL mapping

Tags: java, rest, jersey, servlet-mapping

I am trying to create a very simple REST web service using Java, but I can't get the mapping right...

This is my service:

```
package rest;

@Path("/square/{num}")
public class SquareNumberRest {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String squareNum(@PathParam("num") String num) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(num);
        int squared = n * n;
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(squared);
        return jo.toString();
    }
}
```

My web.xml descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>TestProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>rest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I try to consume the service on the following URL: 
 http://localhost:8080/MyProjectName/square/3

but I'm getting a 404 error.

Comment: Have you tried http://localhost:8080/your-war-name/square/3? Or artifactId?

Comment: Did you try localhost:8080/TestProject/square/3

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the URL context for the project? It's possible that the URL root for the project is right on localhost:8080, which means you'll need to do

http://localhost:8080/square/3 instead.

Comment: I didn't define anything explicitly, I've edited my question and added the entire web.xml file. The http://localhost:8080/square/3 didn't work.